# How this function defines a homeomorphism from $\mathbb B^n$ to itself?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

How the function $F_s(x)=|x|^{s-1}x$ defines a homeomorphism from $\mathbb B^n$ to itself for $s>0$? I find this on Lee's smooth manifold. [image]
For $0<s<1$, this function is not defined on $0$. For $s>1$, the inverse of this function is not defined on $0$.
However, the $\lim_{x\to 0}F_s(x)=0$, so I think if I modify by
$$F_s(x)=
\begin{cases}
|x|^{s-1}x& \text{if $x \neq 0$}\\
0 & \text{if x=0},
\end{cases}$$
then this function is homeomorphism. But how do I know if this modified $F_s$ a diffeomorphism or not for $s\neq 1$?

Comment: Have you determined when $F_s$ is differentiable at $0$? And what about the inverse function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're absolutely right that the function $F_s(x)$ as given is not well defined at $x = 0$. However, your modified function is still not a diffeomorphism of the $n$ ball to itself for $s \neq 1$. To see this, apply the definition of the derivative to $F_s(x)$ at $x = 0$ (and note that $0 < s < 1$):
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{|F_s(x) - 0|}{|x -0|} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{|x|^{s-1}|x| - 0}{|x|} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} |x|^{s-1} = \infty.$$
And hence the function is still not differentiable at the origin.